# Checkbox in jQuery when onclick-button send() doesn't show input in sent email

Tags: jquery

I'm updating my current contact-form by adding a **checkbox**. When clicking on the button = send(), everything is sent correctly to my email except the checkbox. It always says "on". I do understand, that I need to check the checkbox by the jquery, but with all the guides in here, I haven't found success yet (probably due to lack of my general jquery understanding). :-)

As for now it's set up like this (note that I've removed all the other forms to simplify):

```
HTML:
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="form_targeted">Targeted study</label>
   <input type="checkbox" class="form-control checkbox" name="targeted" id="form_targeted"/>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-12">
    <button type="button" onClick="send()" class="btn btn-primary">Submit answers</button>
</div>

jQuery:
<script>
    function send() {
        var form_targeted = jQuery('[name=targeted]').val();

            var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                        document.getElementById("contact-form").innerHTML =
                            this.responseText;
                    }       
                };
                xhttp.open("POST", "php/questionary.php", true);
                xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); 
                xhttp.send("targeted="+form_targeted);
            }
</script>
```

php/questionary.php:

```
<?php
$targeted   = $_POST['targeted'];

$email_from = 'Sender';
$email_subject = 'Subject';
$email_body = "Answers: \n".
    
        "Targeted: $targeted\n".

$to = "info@email.com";
$headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";
$headers = "Reply-To: $email \r\n";

mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);

header("location: php/send_email.html");
?>
```

Looking forward to your answers.

Thanks,
Louis

Comment: have you tried `console.log(form_targeted)` and `echo $targeted` to see if they both have the desired value?

Comment: Hi @CarstenLøvboAndersen. No, I have not. 

I've tried with  if ($('#checkbox').is(":checked")) { } 

Can you exemplify how the console.log(form_targeted) and the echo would be correctly implemented? Many also suggest using a hidden input with value 0 and the form_targeted with value 1. Didn't work, but again - I'm probably not understanding all this correctly. :-)

Comment: Insert `console.log(form_targeted)` on the line after `var form_targeted`. Insert `echo $targeted` on the line after `$targeted   = $_POST['targeted'];`

Comment: If you're looking for a bool `true/false` try `.prop('checked')`. If you're looking for a string `checked/unchecked` try `.attr('checked')`. See [here](https://api.jquery.com/prop/). Aslo, maybe consider [jQuery.post()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) to simplify your client side post code.

Answer (score 0):

I did solve it by changing the following

```
var form_targeted = jQuery('[name=targeted]').val();
```

to

```
var form_targeted = jQuery("[name='targeted']").is(":checked");
```

Anyhow, thanks for the reply :-)

Mange tak for input Carsten.